# How to use d3.js colorScale to change color based on string values rather than numeric values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, export-to-csv

Long story short: I was given a d3.js example to help visualize a `.csv` report that file count numbers for each server in my environment. The goal of the report is to make sure no particular server has too many files in it. So if a server had less than 50 files, the cell would be colored green. If 50-100, colored yellow and anything above 100 colored red.

Here is the specific colorScale code example I am using:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain([50,100,20000])
    .range(["MediumSpringGreen","Yellow","OrangeRed"]);
```

Since this colorScale is designed to have a numeric domain, I am curious how to configure it to accept string values instead?

For an example, I am adding more information to my `.csv` report and instead of just file numbers in servers, I want to show uptime and report things where if there is a cell that says "ONLINE", it would be colored green and if there is a cell that says "OFFLINE", it would be colored red.

--EDIT:--

Hi, so I made the adjustment to use `ordinal` instead of `threshold`:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([" ","STATE : 4 RUNNING","STATE : 1 STOPPED"])
    .range(["White","MediumSpringGreen","OrangeRed"]);
```

However the result is that other cells are being populated as well:

[image]

For an example in the image, my IP address is being colored in as green and "Hostname" is being colored in red.

As of right now, I just want `STATE 4: RUNNING` to be green and `STATE 1: STOPPED` to be red.

Answer (score 0):

You would use an ordinal scale, which maps strings to values.

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(['OFFLINE','ONLINE'])
    .range(['red','green']);
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I took your feedback and adjusted my code to use ordinal instead of threshold, but some cells that I have not specified are being colored in. I made an edit to my main post and added a picture of my result, could you please take a look? Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Eric, may I have some feedback please? I've made an edit to my original post updating the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ordinal scales are forgiving in that if you pass in an "unknown" input value, it will still attempt to output a value. Relative to my answer, an "unknown" value would be a value other than "OFFLINE" and "ONLINE". I suggest setting a default color for an unknown value, such as white. Check out the docs https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#ordinal_unknown